# Deploying multiple instances of an application in kubernetes when both use the same nodePort

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to deploy multiple instance of my application(with different name) on same cluster in kubernetes. My app is  using *nodePort* service for receiving UDP data from outside the cluster.

My service looks something like the below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: newservice
  labels:
    {{- include "..labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: nodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9980
      targetPort: 9980
      nodePort: 30255
      protocol: UDP
  selector:
    {{- include "..selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

But to deploy multiple instance of my application, I need to updated the nodePort number because data source is different for each instance. Is there any way through we can achieve this scenario without updated the port number? Or rather, is there any way for the deployment to know if a port has already been allocated and thereby pick the next port ?

Comment: If you don't specify an explicit `nodePort:` number then Kubernetes will pick something non-conflicting for you; that's probably the easiest path. If this is in the context of a Helm chart you could also pass it as a Helm value, but coordinating the cluster-global port numbers will be a challenge.

Comment: David Maze is right. If you don't specify `nodePort` explicitly, Kubernetes control plane will automatically allocates a port from a range specified by `--service-node-port-range` flag (default: `30000-32767`).

Comment: thanks guys. The actual issue I am facing is that I need to deploy multiple instances of my app and this deployment might sometimes be on a single node cluster. I have a an application sending UDP data to my deployment and I need to specify the port number to the sender. Now, if a restart does happen, I do not want to go back to the sender and reconfigure the port. Maybe I'll look for ways to either restructure my deployment or my architecture.

Comment: any progress ? 
Did you solve the problem ?